# Internal-use-only class in a deeply nested Perl module - avoiding awkward naming

Tags: perl, oop, package

Suppose a Perl module named `MyApplication/Subcomponent.pm`, and like usual the file starts with `package MyApplication::Subcomponent;`  This module happens to define a collection of utility functions.  One of those utility functions needs to create an instance of a local, internal-use-only class.  The class definition is very simple so I'll just paste it here.  It's a [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) class that saves and restores the value of an environment variable.

```perl
{
  package MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_ENV_THING;

  sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    $ENV{THING} = ${ $self };
  }

  sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $old_value = $ENV{THING};
    $ENV{THING} = shift;
    return bless \$old_value, $class;
  }
}
```

It's my understanding that I have to give this class a name in the global space of package names, and I have to name it starting from the root: I can't just write `package restore_ENV_THING;` because that would stomp on the *top* level of the namespace.

So here's the question: What, if anything, could I do so that the code that *uses* this class -- which is guaranteed to be in the same file as the above code block and lexically below it -- could be written

```perl
sub utility_routine_that_needs_to_save_and_restore_THING {
  my $restorer = restore_ENV_THING->new($temporary_value);
  ...
}
```

instead of

```perl
sub utility_routine_that_needs_to_save_and_restore_THING {
  my $restorer = MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_ENV_THING
    ->new($temporary_value);
  ...
}
```

If you know a trick that would allow me *not* to have to give the class a name in the global space of package names (perhaps something not entirely unlike what `open my $fh, ...` does?) I would like to hear about that too.

---

Note that `MyApplication` has some unusual constraints on its code:

- The oldest supported version of Perl is 5.006.  Yes, you read that right, 5.006.  In particular this means I cannot use lexically scoped subs.
- No CPAN modules may be used, only modules that were included in the stdlib as of 5.006.  This is why I don't just use [Guard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Guard) or [Scope::Guard](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scope::Guard), and why I am manually defining the class using primitives.
- Cannot ship any XS code itself.  This is why I am using `sub DESTROY` for RAII even though that won't work right if the guard object is mishandled in the caller; as far as I know, there's no way to do better without dropping down to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_ENV_THING->new($temporary_value);
```

is short for

```perl
"MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_ENV_THING"->new($temporary_value);
```

so all you need is

```perl
use constant restore_ENV_THING => "MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_ENV_THING";

restore_ENV_THING->new($temporary_value);
```

Answer (score 3):

Would a package [alias](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) do?

```
{
  package MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_ENV_THING;

  BEGIN {
      *MS:: = *MyApplication::Subcomponent::;  # (initials for name)?
  };

  sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    $ENV{THING} = ${ $self };
  }

  sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $old_value = $ENV{THING};
    $ENV{THING} = shift;
    return bless \$old_value, $class;
  }
}
```

Now it can be used as `MS::restore_ENV_THING`.

This is global over all packages and scopes, being a compile time alias. It does muck with the `main::` symbol table but that should be fine as long as you pick a "free" name.

And then there are packages, like [aliased](https://metacpan.org/pod/aliased) pragma, [Package::Alias](https://metacpan.org/pod/Package::Alias), and a number of others, but they do come with subtleties so I'd recommend reading up on them first. I found the builtin aliasing as shown above a fine solution whenever I used it.

Comment: That's not actually different from declaring `package MS;` in the first place though, is it?  Both muck with the main:: symbol table and that's what I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: @zwol I thought the package need be under `MyApplication::Subcomponent` (so in `MyApplication/Subcomponent` directory on the filesystem); then you can't call it `MS` (as in `package MS;`), as you nicely stated, since then that file would have to be on the top of hierarchy.  The symbol table isn't a problem -- we  have to pick names carefully for any package anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself quite right. `MS::restore_env_THING`  puts `MS` into the main:: namespace; having the name of the class be `restore_env_THING` with no package prefix puts `restore_env_THING` into the `main::` namespace. Both are equally problematic in context of this application.

Comment: @zwol Is this going to be used by other packages, not directly in`main`?

Comment: `restore_env_THING` is only used by code in the `MyApplication::Subcomponent::` package.  What I would ideally like is for that name to be only _visible_ within the `MyApplication::Subcomponent` package (like all the other stuff that isn't in its @EXPORT(_OK)), but not to have to type out `MyApplication::Subcomponent::restore_env_THING` each time it's used.

Comment: @zwol If it's indeed used mostly by packages in its own namespace -- so if its file lives in a directory where its users are -- then you can call it just `package restore_env_THING;` and packages from the same namespace can then load it by `use restore_env_THING;`.  (You'd still be able to use it from other code, but then that code would have to add its location to its `@INC`, by doing `use lib '...';`.)

Comment: @zwol  I noticed only now this in the question: "_code that uses this class -- which is guaranteed to be in the same file as the above code block and lexically below it_" ... what kind of "_code that uses this class_" is that -- Is this package meant to be defined _inside_ of another package?  Then the main part of the question is easy ... can you clarify this? As for symbol table, I think that once a `package` is declared anywhere it can be dug up somehwere in `%main::`

Comment: @zwol My confusion, at this point, in short: (1) is this package in a file inside the directory `MyApplication/Subcomponent`, and used only by other packages in that directory? (2) or, is the package _inside a file with another package_, which is in that directory?

Comment: The package is defined inside a file with another package; the sub that needs it is an export from the larger package. I realize this goes against the grain of the language, but there's just one place that needs to use this class and it seems excessive to make a separate file for eleven lines of actual code.

Comment: @zwol Oh.  That kinda changes things a little :). You're right, that "class" should be scaled down as much as possible. ( Btw, would good ol' `local` help then?  If you really mean to tweak `%ENV`, that's a global and `local` protects its outside-the-scope value. Like `perl -wE'sub tt { say $ENV{HOME}; { local $ENV{HOME} = q(/ha/ha/); say $ENV{HOME} }; say $ENV{HOME} }; tt()` )

Comment: OMG. `local $ENV{THING} = "newvalue"` does exactly what I want without any other greebles. You just made the entire class unnecessary. (I admit I never actually bothered learning what `local` is _for_, besides `local $/ = undef` and the like. I would have assumed that `local` changes to `%ENV` _didn't_ affect the environment passed down to subprocesses, but they do!)

Comment: (I think I'm going to accept the other answer, though, since it directly addresses the question I asked, but know that you have answered the question I _should have_ asked :-)

Comment: @zwol Yeah, interesting how a conversation about a problem can be useful :).  Yes, ikegami's answer is spot on for what you asked (given your clarifications in this thread, for me -- perhaps it was clear enough from the question on its own but I didn't see it).

Comment: @zwol I'd also add -- that's a nice idea with the class; it implements `local` :)